# JSON schema for an array

Tags: arrays, json, jsonschema

I've a JSON Schema and a sample input. I need to write a generic schema which can handle the array regardless the length of the array. Currently, I need to write schema for each of the index in the array.

**JSON Schema**

```
{
  "title":"Example",
  "$schema":"http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type":"array",
  "items":[
    {
     "oneOf":[
       {
         "multipleOf": 3
       }
     ]
    },
    {
      "oneOf":[
       {
         "multipleOf": 3
       },
       {
         "multipleOf": 5
       }
     ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**Sample Input**

```
[
  3,
  5
]
```

I need a schema which can validate `[1,3,5,6,3,5,4,......]` (regardless the length)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put a schema directly in `items`, instead of using an array, then it applies to all array items:

```
{
    "type": "array",
    "items": {
        "oneOf": [
            {"multipleOf": 3},
            {"multipleOf": 5}
        ]
    }
}
```

---

If you want to describe an initial set of items with specific schemas, and all the following ones with a generic one, then use an array with `items`, and a schema in `additionalItems`:

```
{
    "type": "array",
    "items": [
        {"multipleOf": 3},
        ...
    ],
    "additionalItems": {
        "oneOf": [
            {"multipleOf": 3},
            {"multipleOf": 5}
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: What if I want a schema to validate a array in which the '0'th index of the array should be multiple of 2 and rest can have both multiples of 2 and 5. And the '0'th index is required.

Comment: You will also need to include `"minItems": 1` to make the '0'th index required.

Comment: For the second schema with `additionalItems` the input `[3,7]` is getting validated. It should not be ryt?

Comment: what if the array can contain a single null value like this `[ null ]`